# Is there any way of using custom icons in primereact tree?

Tags: reactjs, tree, primereact

is there any way of using custom icons in primereact tree? I've tried importing them in css file and using them like that but it did not work.

Here is a sample of json file with primereact icon usage.

```
"key": "0-0",
"label": "Work",
"data": "Work Folder",
"icon": "pi pi-fw pi-cog"
```

Icon usage in css

```
.myIcon {
background-image: url('imgpath');
}
```

Here is a sample of json file with custom icon usage

```
"key": "0-0",
"label": "Work",
"data": "Work Folder",
"icon": "myIcon"
```

Would really appreciate help with this one

EDIT:
So I've managed to solve this problem by replacing background-image with content.

Css below:

```
.m-icon {
 content: url("../images/module.png");
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this example show you how to do exactly that? https://primefaces.org/primereact/showcase/#/tree/selection

Comment: I've already managed to solve it with using content instead of backround-image in cc

Comment: You should post your solution below here then and then we can mark this question answered.

Comment: Sorry about that, newbie here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to solve this problem by replacing background-image with content.

Css below:

```
.m-icon {
 content: url("../images/module.png");
}
```